# JUnit test not working correctly with Timer

Tags: java, dictionary, timer, junit

I have a snippet of code that executes a timer, that then executes a method after a short delay (obviously).  I'm having a spot of bother when it comes to my JUnit tests (end-to-end and integration tests pass fine) for this module.

Here is the timer code:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Deleting from the map");
            deleteFromMap(mapKey);  // This method actually deletes "mapKey" from the map
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catch the exception
        }
    }
}, delay); // "delay" is passing into the method
```

So in my JUnit test, I check this delay by checking the map 
still has the value of mapKey before the delay expires (I'm testing with 15000ms, so I have plenty of time).  However, when I perform this check, it throws an exception saying that mapKey cannot be found.  I am also not getting the "Deleting from the map" log message.

I have tested by adding a `Thread.sleep(20000)` in my JUnit code, and the logs are displayed find by the Timer thread, but if the method in the timer has not been executed, without the `Thread.sleep(...)`, why does it not find it in the map?

Is there something about Timers that JUnit doesn't play well with?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe it doesn't exist in the map?

also: I would recommend against code like:

catch ( Exception e) {
  // Catch the Exception
}

simply hiding everything that goes wrong won't solve any problems you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your test is kind of useless... What you're trying to test is the Timer class, which you didn't write (isn't it?). I guess that class works just fine...

You should concentrate on testing your own code, and it's business logic. In this case, what you could test is the deleteFromMap method.